# Bash read lines and keep indents

Tags: bash

I have written this simple function to read a template file, replace a few values in it, and then save it to an actual file.

However, I'd like to keep the indents that are in the template file. As of now, its just producing a new file without indents at all.

```
function create_vhost_conf_from_template {
    while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        line=${line/\[SERVERNAME\]/$server_name}
        line=${line/\[VHOSTROOT\]/\/var\/www\/vhosts\/$vhost\/httpdocs}
        echo $line | tee -a /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/$vhost.conf
    done < "/root/templates/$1"
}
```

Comment: Can you share an example of your template, and an example of what your expected output would look like?

Comment: `echo "$line"` :)

Comment: Thank you @PesaThe :) Saved me from some headache

Comment: @OleHaugset Take a look at [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/). It is a great tool that can identify issues like this :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip :) As you prolly noticed, bash aint my "first language"